# Make Pandas Dataframe column equal to value in another Dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes as below

df1

```
id     first_name      surname     state
1                  
88     
190
2509  
....
```

df2

```
id     given_name      surname     state    street_num
17     John            Doe         NY       5
88     Tom             Murphy      CA       423
190    Dave            Casey       KY       250
....
```

df3

```
id     first_name      family_name state    car
1      John            Woods       NY       ford
74     Tom             Kite        FL       vw
2509   Mike            Johnson     KY       toyota
```

Some id's from df1 are in df2 and others are in df3. There are also id's in df2 and df3 that are not in df1.

**EDIT:** there are also some id's in df1 that re not in either df2 or df3.

I want to fill the columns in df1 with the values in the dataframe containing the id. However, I do not want all columns (so i think merge is not suitable). I have tried to use the isin function but that way I could not update records individually and got an error. This was my attempt using isin:

```
df1.loc[df1.index.isin(df2.index), 'first_name'] = df2.given_name
```

Is there an easy way to do this without iterating through the dataframes checking if index matches?

Answer (score 3):

I think you first need to `rename` your columns to align the `DataFrame`s in [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to filter by `df1.index` and `df1.columns`:

```
df21 = df2.rename(columns={'given_name':'first_name'})
df31 = df3.rename(columns={'family_name':'surname'})
df = pd.concat([df21, df31]).reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
     first_name  surname state
d                             
1          John    Woods    NY
88          Tom   Murphy    CA
190        Dave    Casey    KY
2509       Mike  Johnson    KY
```

EDIT: If need [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) of indices only:

```
df4 = pd.concat([df21, df31])
df = df4.reindex(index=df1.index.intersection(df4.index), columns=df1.columns)
```

Comment: You'll first need to rename and drop certain columns in `df` and `df2`, but that part is easy enough.

Comment: @Charles - Thank you.

Comment: I thought this would work but I had forgot to mention that there are also some id's in df1 that are not present in either df2 or df3. Any suggestions?

Comment: @daragh - and need remove this `id` ?

Comment: No, I need to keep the id's not present in other dataframes also

Comment: No, I am getting the following error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @datagh What return `print (df4[df4.index.duplicated(keep=False)])` and `print (df1[df1.index.duplicated(keep=False)])` ? If there are duplicated rows need remove them?

Comment: The duplicates are not in the index. But there are duplicates in other columns which cannot be removed

Comment: @daragh I dont undesrand. There are duplicated columns in df4? How it is possible, because dataframe in concat are aligned?