# Getting NaN's instead of the correct values inside dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe of zeros using this syntax:

```
ltv = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros([actual_df.shape[0], 6]),
                        columns=['customer_id',
                                'actual_total',
                                'predicted_num_purchases',
                                'predicted_value',
                                'predicted_total',
                                'error'], dtype=np.float32)
```

It comes out perfectly as expected

```
customer_id | actual_total | predicted_num_purchases | predicted_value | predicted_total | error
0   0.0          0.0             0.0                         0.0              0.0           0.0
1   0.0          0.0             0.0                         0.0              0.0           0.0
2   0.0          0.0             0.0                         0.0              0.0           0.0
```

When I run this syntax:

```
ltv['customer_id'] = actual_df['customer_id']
```

I get all NaNs in `ltv['customer_id']`. What is causing this and how can I prevent it from happening?

**NB**: I also checked `actual_df`and there are no NaNs inside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need same index values in both (and also same length of both DataFrames).

So first solution is create default `RabgeIndex` in `actual_df`, in `ltv` is not specify, so created by default:

```
actual_df = actual_df.reset_index(drop=True)
ltv['customer_id'] = actual_df['customer_id']
```

Or add parameter `index` to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
ltv = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros([actual_df.shape[0], 6]),
                        columns=['customer_id',
                                'actual_total',
                                'predicted_num_purchases',
                                'predicted_value',
                                'predicted_total',
                                'error'], dtype=np.float32,
                        index=actual_df.index)

ltv['customer_id'] = actual_df['customer_id']
```

Comment: This sounds familiar :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401320/make-pandas-dataframe-column-equal-to-value-in-another-dataframe-based-on-index

Answer (score 0):

Another option (more complicated than jezrael's great answer) is using `pd.concat()` followed by `.drop()`:

```
ltv = pd.concat([ltv.drop(columns=['customer_id']),actual_df[['customer_id']]],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```